# TSQL Finding items not selected

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I currently have data sitting in Table A like the below.

```
Title_1 | Contract A
Title_1 | Contract B
Title_1 | Contract C
Title_2 | Contract A
Title_2 | Contract D
```

I am using

```
SELECT DISTINCT T2.Title, SUBSTRING(
               SELECT '; ' + Contract as [text()]
               FROM dbo.TitleContracts T1
               WHERE T1.Title = T2.Title
               AND Contract IN (
                  SELECT Contract FROM dbo.ValidContracts
                  )
               FOR XML PATH ('')
           ), 2, 1000) [ContractList]
FROM dbo.TitleContracts T2
```

the above query to turn the data into the below results. However what I'm trying to also do is find the list of Contracts for each Title using the ValidContracts table that weren't selected. So if we have Contract A-D then Title_1 would return Contract D and Title_2 would return Contract B & Contract C.

```
Title_1 | Contract A; Contract B; Contract C
Title_2 | Contract A; Contract D
```

I'm probably way over thinking this, but nothing I've tried seems to be taking me in the correct direction. I'm not asking you to write my code, but a nudge into the correct direction would be amazing.

Comment: Do you have a lookup table of contracts, or is the only way to know that a contract is missing is that some other Title in TableA has it?  You mention a "ValidContracts" table.  What does that table contain?

Comment: Do you mean `NOT IN`?

Comment: @TabAlleman the table dbo.ValidContracts has a list of all currently active Contracts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a CTE:

```
with c_list as
(
select 'Contract A' as TheContract
union all
select 'Contract B'
union all
select 'Contract C'
union all
select 'Contract D'
)
, MixList as
(
select distinct T2.Title, C1.TheContract
from TitleContracts T2
cross join c_list C1
)
select M3.*
from MixList M3
left join TitleContracts T3
on T3.Title = M3.Title
and M3.TheContract = T3.Contract
where T3.T3.Title is null
```

Comment: A cross join is what I was considering previously, but I wasn't sure if that would be the best approach. While I don't need the CTE for the list of contracts everything else here is perfectly and I really appreciate your input.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, instead of using an IN to peek in ValidContracts, do a RIGHT JOIN to it, and filter for rows where the left side is NULL.